# SSL client-hello, message body structure

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to work with SSL manually without using libs as OpenSSL etc... And I have fault on 1st step with Hello message from client.

From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785811%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
It must consist of:
ClientVersion 3,1
ClientRandom[32]
SessionID: None (new session)
Suggested Cipher Suites:
   TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
   TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Suggested Compression Algorithm: NONE
```

In my code ( C/C++ ), I have created message on this way:

```
char *request = "ClientVersion 3,1\r\nClientRandom[32]\r\n
SessionID: None (new session)\r\n
Suggested Cipher Suites:\r\n
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA\r\n
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA\r\n
Suggested Compression Algorithm: NONE\r\n";
```

But after recv() functions, I've got 0 in result, so what's wrong in my message structure?

PS
In HTTP-proto there is a place, when must be double \r\n ( which splits the headers and the body message ), may be, there must be something like this or not?

Answer (score 7):

You need to take a good look at [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt), rather than just making things up. For example the newlines between the elements of the message are a figment of your imagination.

But why you think you can work with SSL 'manually' is a mystery. You can't, and you don't need to. Reimplementing SSL is a major task and you don't have the resources to do it. Use your library: OpenSSL, JSSE, etc.

Comment: it's not a mystery, it's normal. I think I could work, cause: somebobdy can do it ( why not me? ), it's not 3-rd party libs which free you from minding process, you shall know how does SSL work correctly, I have worked with HTTP, FTP, POP3, IMAP on TCP with C/C++ and don't use ready stuff, also were implemeting substring search classics algorithms for this work. Such work has much more goals for knowladge.

Comment: @user167908, SSL/TLS is somewhat more difficult than HTTP, FTP, POP3 and IMAP. It's not a simple text-based request/response models like those protocols. Take a good look at the RFC (and where it talks about XDR at least). It usually takes a while to understand it. It's easy to get things wrong and obtain an insecure implementation. Look at packets with something like Wireshark to get an idea of what's going on. The pseudo-commands you've tried to send are merely textual representations of the messages: useful, but largely simplified.

Comment: @user167908 It's not normal, it's a mystery. You can do it yourself *if* you can implement or interface to several dozen cipher suites and if you know how to read an RFC. The evidence here says that you don't qualify, sorry. There are several high-quality implementations already available. Why you think you want another remains a mystery.

Comment: @ejp you don't understand at all, you can only qualify if you kave knowladge, but if you refuse to get knowladge and only use 3-rd party libs you will be out from this qualify. If you wannt to eualify you must implement it by yourself, there is not another way. Only you do it or not - the only mark of quilify. Some you must do it munallly without opensll etc if you want get level, I have choosed this way. I know, that I know less, but I can gross and I'll do it.

Comment: @user167908, I think what EJP is trying to say here is that it's clear from your example (e.g. `"ClientVersion 3,1\r\nClientRandom[32]\r\n"`) that you haven't gone anyway near the RFC. You should at least try to understand what existing implementations do before starting to write your own. Even for someone who already knows what the message structures should look like, it's a massive project. Of course, being a security protocol, it's better if someone else reviews the code too. Note that you're likely to have to implement RFC 5280 and RFC 6125 once you're done with RFC 2246.

Comment: @user167908 You can only get the knowledge you seek in the reference I cited. Uninformed guesswork will not do.

Comment: Criticisms should be constructive and not just negative.